# Show/Load pictures from URL in MS Access Image control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm asking this question and going to answer it, as I think many of us asked and struggled with this situation before. Hope this helps future readers and developers.

**How to show/load hyperlink/web pictures into ms access image control?**

```
Me.ImageControl.Picture = "https://example.com/SamplePicture.png" 'Throws an error but
Me.ImageControl.Picture = "C:\SamplePicture.png" ' Works
```

**Question**: I would like to use the Image control and show pictures from the web.

---

Plese do improve my answer and or add your methods.

for those who wish to debate about answering with own github project
[Spam? or no spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317127/flagging-as-spam-an-answer-that-promotes-a-github-project)

**Too broad?** Some questions are truely too broad to answer or depend on the user situation. Whether this question is too broad? I'm not sure. The question is how do I load online picture into an image control? below you will read nice methods from everyone's approach. Including mine.

I wanted to register this question in SO because most google search about image and hyperlinks are non SO results and most aren't nice to read like SO.

Comment: Can you please also provide a reasonable use case? Normally, a web browser control is a fine way to show images from the web, and using an image control is just a hassle.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: You don't need the web browser control just for retrieving pictures. The _URLDownloadTo[Cache]File_ APIs will do just fine, and probably faster.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth IMHO, using web-control isn't a direct answer. Tt's a wayaround wich would come with own issues and question when using it.

Comment: @KrishKM did I provide it as an answer? Your question is oddly constrained to make most other answers not fit, which is one of the reasons I don't like it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth IMO, you don't need to like anything. SO is a library/community, different people read different things and take different approaches :) Please do provide your "way-around"  approach with web-browser method. I'm sure someone is after that approach too.

Comment: As you said, it's not an answer to this question. I've previously provided it on questions where it was appropriate. Also, I don't answer questions I think should be closed, perhaps if my vote expires...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth your opinion or answer isn't summoned here and SO isn't your personal site to filter questions by your own preferences. There is a valid question and three answers illustrating three different approaches. Besides, all your inputs sofar doesn't even contribute anything towards to the question. Stop being hostile and move on.

Comment: Eh... I'm just replying to your invitation to write up an answer (after you told me that my approach wasn't an answer, weird...). If you think I'm overly hostile, or violating the be-nice policy, you're free to flag or raise it on meta. I'm just trying to make sure the content on the ms-access tag is  correct and abides by the site rules

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth nope.. I'm the nicest guy here :) :) feel free to add your answer please!

Answer (score 3):

MS Access Image control is great for loading local files but if you are saving your pictures as web-url, you will have hard time showing them. If you try to assign any `url` to the `Image.picture` property, you will receive `"Microsoft cannot open the file"` error.

There are some way-arounds for this.

1. Download and save the picture and load into the image control
2. Use web-browser control
3. Buy thir-party controls
4. (any other method i don't know of)

All of above will work but they come either with extra code or too much footprints on the local system. I.e. Downloading and loading image would leave you with downlod and cleaning up the mess after finish showing pictures part.

Web-browser control requires some HTML wrappers so you can do some basic sizing. Some would buy third-party controls but most of us don't want to install any activx control. Especially if you have to ship your access file to someone else.

**My approach**
Using .NET I'm developing a collection of *application independent plug-in-components for VBA environment* (see my [GitHub](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS)). Hoping to expand and ease some of daily used tasks in VBA.

Recently I wrote a function that can read a hyperlink and return PictureData for MS Access Image control. This allows you to load any pictures from online and show it without too much hassle.
[Download sample](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/tree/master/samples)

Here is some information about the dll function.

```
  'Download the sample database from my github and see how to plug-in the dll.
  'Dll function fromt the dll. If you want to write your own vba wrapper
  'PictureFromUrl(
    string URL,             :  Image url. web url or local path
    bool ShowError = false, : Show error notification when url cannot be loaded
    long sender = 0         : Sender HWND, not used now.
    )
```

In VBA.

```
  'VBA Wrapper (used for simplicity)
  'ImageControlGetImage(ImagePath as string, optional ShowError=true)

'Loading web url
Private Sub Command147_Click()
    Dim WebPicture As String
    WebPicture = "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1001697?s=460&v=4"

    Me.Image113.PictureData = gDll.ImageControlGetImage(WebPicture, ShowError:=True)
End Sub
```

.

```
'    
'Same function can be used to load local files
'
Private Sub Command149_Click()
    Dim WebPicture As String
    WebPicture = "F:\Projects\VBA_DLL\dialogboxgreen.png"

    Me.Image113.PictureData = gDll.ImageControlGetImage(WebPicture, ShowError:=True)

End Sub
```

If you would like to read urls from your table

instead using the control source property, use the on current event in your form to load the pictures.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  'Load pictures 
    Me.Image8.PictureData = gDll.ImageControlGetImage([url], True)
End Sub
```

[image: Picture showing image loading]

Comment: I think answering your own question with an off-site resource created by yourself is not a good fit for this site. If you wish to promote your own plugin, and get input, Stack Overflow is not the place for it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think this has already been debated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317127/flagging-as-spam-an-answer-that-promotes-a-github-project)

Comment: Somewhat, but there's a difference between sharing a rather long solution and using GitHub because it doesn't fit, or sharing a separate product (add-in, library, etc.). Questions requesting these are usually flagged as a request for an off-site resource. You haven't requested one, but you have asked a question that's so broad it requires one to answer it. Anyway, like also discussed in that thread, I've asked SOCVR to review it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  Chil! the end goal of this site is to educate and be informative. You can't deny the fact that this answer opens up the posibility to future readers that it can be done with .NET wrappers. or there is [one kind] of way of doing it. Besides, i will look into the off-site-resource thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is certainly no need for a .Net plugin for this.

One VBA function, the usual API call, and basic SQL, is all that is needed, and you can even control the caching of the downloaded pictures (Access demo application for download as well):

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

Full code for both 32- and 64-bit is at *GitHub*: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl)

The function is extremely easy to use - it simply adds the picture path to the source query of the form or report:

```
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"

    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String

    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If

    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If

        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext

        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If

    UrlContent = Result

End Function
```

The declarations and helper functions are here:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) _
        As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToCacheFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToCacheFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal cchFileName As Long, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) _
        As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
        As Long

    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToCacheFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToCacheFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal cchFileName As Long, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
        As Long
#End If
'

' Download a file or a page with public access from the web.
' Returns 0 if success, error code if not.
'
' If parameter NoOverwrite is True, no download will be attempted
' if an existing local file exists, thus this will not be overwritten.
'
' Examples:
'
' Download a file:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg"
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProjectProfile.jpg"
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName)
'
' Download a page:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print"
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProject1022704.html"
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName)
'
' Error codes:
' -2146697210   "file not found".
' -2146697211   "domain not found".
' -1            "local file could not be created."
'
' 2004-12-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added check for local file.
' 2017-06-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added option to no overwrite the local file.
'
Public Function DownloadFile( _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    ByVal LocalFileName As String, _
    Optional ByVal NoOverwrite As Boolean) _
    As Long

    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNotFound As Long = -1

    Dim Result  As Long

    If NoOverwrite = True Then
        ' Page or file should not be overwritten.
        ' Check that the local file exists.
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            ' File exists. Don't proceed.
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' Download file or page.
    ' Return success or error code.
    Result = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, LocalFileName & vbNullChar, BindFDefault, 0)

    If Result = ErrorNone Then
        ' Page or file was retrieved.
        ' Check that the local file exists.
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) = "" Then
            Result = ErrorNotFound
        End If
    End If

    DownloadFile = Result

End Function

' Download a file or a page with public access from the web as a cached file of Internet Explorer.
' Returns the full path of the cached file if success, an empty string if not.
'
' Examples:
'
' Download a file:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg"
'   Result = DownloadCacheFile(Url)
'   Result -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\B2IHEJQZ\{a82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23}[2].png
'
' Download a page:
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print"
'   Result = DownloadCacheFile(Url)
'   Result -> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\B2IHEJQZ\Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur[1].htm
'
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DownloadCacheFile( _
    ByVal Url As String) _
    As String

    Const BufferLength  As Long = 1024
    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0

    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim LocalFileName   As String
    Dim Result          As Long

    ' Create buffer for name of downloaded and/or cached file.
    FileName = Space(BufferLength - 1) & vbNullChar
    ' Download file or page.
    ' Return name of cached file in parameter FileName.
    Result = URLDownloadToCacheFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, FileName, BufferLength, BindFDefault, 0)

    ' Trim file name.
    LocalFileName = Split(FileName, vbNullChar)(0)

    DownloadCacheFile = LocalFileName

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for this approach.