# mysql access database - Image display

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have created an access database 2016 with backend MySQL tables, however on my form I require an image to display.

After reading plenty of articles online I have decided to keep the images in a separate folder in the same location as the database so I don't overload it.

However I have created an attachment section (hyperlink) on my form so I can save the filepath to the image in the backend table, If I click on the filepath I am able to view the image but I would like to have a small sample of the image available to view on the database form.

[image: design view of db]

If anyone could advise how I would go about this it would be greatly appreciated.

[Update of information added into control source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcQZ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Form: \`abc.Picture="xyz.jpg"\` makes listbox & textboxes "blink" once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207997/access-form-abc-picture-xyz-jpg-makes-listbox-textboxes-blink-once)

Comment: @June7 I have tried these but it doesn't appear to be working, I am still getting a blank screen instead of an image populating.

Comment: The technique is proven and I have used it many times. No way to debug your situation because there is no code to review. Your question does not fit SO.

Comment: @June7 I have added in the additional coding I have put in for the control source does this look correct?

Comment: Code should be text not image in question. The expression syntax looks fine except probably another '\' character. But since I don't know data in Text127 nor the names of files, no idea if this will work. What does "doesn't appear to be working" mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Your question as presented is still inadequate.

Comment: Read here: [Show/Load pictures from URL in MS Access Image control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296883/9199828). I have used it and it works pretty good. It downloas to a temp folder an image and then you can use it in forms and reports (in my case, reports).