# VBA: Download a picture via HTTPS

Tags: vba, ms-access, winhttp, winhttprequest, grafana-api

I'm trying to download a picture from a website (Grafana monitoring tool, API) using VBA (MS Access 2016). It's a HTTPS address using a self signed ceritificat and requires username and password for authentication.

I'm currently using the following code to download the picture:

```
Function DownloadFile(ByVal myURL As String, ByVal LocalFileName As String) 
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    WinHttpReq.Option(4) = 13056          'Ignore SSL Errors
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
    WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
    WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive"
    WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
       Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
       oStream.Open
       oStream.Type = 1
       oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
       oStream.SaveToFile LocalFileName, 2
       oStream.Close
    Else
       MsgBox "Returncode:" & WinHttpReq.Status & " Unable to download picture."
    End If
End function
```

If I paste the HTTPS-URL into my browser I get the right picture. This picture I would like to have as a PNG file downloaded by the code above. But instead of the picture I get the following HTML code downloaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script>
  !(function() {
    if ('PerformanceLongTaskTiming' in window) {
      var g = (window.__tti = { e: [] });
      g.o = new PerformanceObserver(function(l) {
        g.e = g.e.concat(l.getEntries());
      });
      g.o.observe({ entryTypes: ['longtask'] });
    }
  })();
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000" />

<title>Grafana</title>
<base href="/" />

<link
  rel="preload"
  href="public/fonts/roboto/RxZJdnzeo3R5zJw.woff2"
  as="font"
  crossorigin
/>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="public/img/fav32.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="public/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="mask-icon" href="public/img/grafana_mask_icon.svg" color="#F05A28" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/build/grafana.dark.4d0490af40c.css" />

<script>
  performance.mark('css done blocking');
</script>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797" />
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="public/img/browserconfig.xml" />
  </head>
  <body class="theme-dark app-grafana">
<style>
  .preloader {
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .preloader__enter {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: preloader-fade-in;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-delay: 1.35s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .preloader__bounce {
    text-align: center;
    animation-name: preloader-bounce;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  .preloader__logo {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: preloader-squash;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='351px' height='365px' viewBox='0 0 351 365' style='enable-background:new 0 0 351 365%3b' xml:space='preserve'%3e %3cstyle type='text/css'%3e .st0%7bfill:url(%23SVGID_1_)%3b%7d %3c/style%3e %3cg id='Layer_1_1_'%3e %3c/g%3e %3clinearGradient id='SVGID_1_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='175.5' y1='445.4948' x2='175.5' y2='114.0346'%3e %3cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%23FFF100'/%3e %3cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%23F05A28'/%3e %3c/linearGradient%3e %3cpath class='st0' d='M342%2c161.2c-0.6-6.1-1.6-13.1-3.6-20.9c-2-7.7-5-16.2-9.4-25c-4.4-8.8-10.1-17.9-17.5-26.8 c-2.9-3.5-6.1-6.9-9.5-10.2c5.1-20.3-6.2-37.9-6.2-37.9c-19.5-1.2-31.9%2c6.1-36.5%...2c1.6%2c2.3%2c3%2c2.1c1.5-0.1%2c2.6-1.3%2c2.6-2.8C342.6%2c170.4%2c342.5%2c166.1%2c342%2c161.2z'/%3e %3c/svg%3e");
  }

  .preloader__text {
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: preloader-fade-in;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-delay: 1.8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .preloader__text--fail {
    display: none;
  }

  .preloader--done .preloader__bounce,
  .preloader--done .preloader__logo {
    animation-name: none;
    display: none;
  }

  .preloader--done .preloader__logo,
  .preloader--done .preloader__text {
    display: none;
    color: #ff5705 !important;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .preloader--done .preloader__text--fail {
    display: block;
  }

  [ng\:cloak],
  [ng-cloak],
  .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>

<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__enter">
    <div class="preloader__bounce">
      <div class="preloader__logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="preloader__text">Loading Grafana</div>
  <div class="preloader__text preloader__text--fail">
    <p>
      <strong>If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files</strong>
      <br />
      <br />
    </p>
    <p>
      1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.<br /><br />
      2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath<br />
      <br />
      3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn
      build<br />
      <br />
      4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help<br />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<grafana-app class="grafana-app" ng-cloak>
  <sidemenu class="sidemenu"></sidemenu>
  <app-notifications-list class="page-alert-list"></app-notifications-list>
  <dashboard-search></dashboard-search>

  <div class="main-view">
            <div ng-view class="scroll-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</grafana-app>

<script>
    window.grafanaBootData = {
      user: {"isSignedIn":false,"id":0,"login":"","email":"","name":"","lightTheme":false,"orgCount":0,"orgId":0,"orgName":"","orgRole":"","isGrafanaAdmin":false,"gravatarUrl":"","timezone":"browser","locale":"en-US","helpFlags1":0,"hasEditPermissionInFolders":false},
      settings: {"alertingEnabled":true,"alertingErrorOrTimeout":"alerting","alertingMinInterval":1,"alertingNoDataOrNullValues":"no_data","allowOrgCreate":false,"appSubUrl":"","authProxyEnabled":false,"buildInfo":{"buildstamp":1582200229,"commit":"3fa63cfc34","edition":"Open Source","env":"production","hasUpdate":false,"isEnterprise":false,"latestVersion":"","version":"6.6.2"},"datasources":{"-- Dashboard --":{"meta":{"type":"datasource","name":"--...plugins","url":"/plugins"}]},{"id":"help","text":"Help","subTitle":"Grafana v6.6.2 (3fa63cfc34)","icon":"gicon gicon-question","url":"#","sortWeight":-1200,"hideFromMenu":true}]
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var preloader = document.getElementsByClassName("preloader");
      if (preloader.length) {
        preloader[0].className = "preloader preloader--done";
      }
    };
</script>

<script src="public/build/runtime.4d0490a94b199a11f40c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/build/angular~app.4d0490a94b199a11f40c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/build/app.4d0490a94b199a11f40c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/build/moment~app.4d0490a94b199a11f40c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/build/vendors~app.4d0490a94b199a11f40c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  performance.mark('js done blocking');
</script>
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem in VBA?

Comment: Are you really tied to this method? Maybe try API function. See Gustav answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296020/show-load-pictures-from-url-in-ms-access-image-control

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading Images from URL and Renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184990/downloading-images-from-url-and-renaming)

Comment: I researched already a lot and figured out that other methods like XMLHTTP or URLDownloadToFile do not support HTTPS. See https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/506439/Downloading-files-with-VBScript
The only method I found which can handle HTTPS is WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051960/vba-winhttp-to-download-file-from-password-proteced-https-website/

Comment: Thank you @June7 for the recommendation. I tested the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051960/vba-winhttp-to-download-file-from-password-proteced-https-website/ and it ends up with the same problem. The file is a HTML doc instead of a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I was an authentication issue with Grafana. The code below fixed the problem:

```
Function DownloadFile(ByVal myURL As String, ByVal LocalFileName As String) 
     Dim WinHttpReq As Object
     Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
     WinHttpReq.Option(4) = 13056          'Ignore SSL Errors
     WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
     WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
     WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
     WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Proxy-Connection", "Keep-Alive"
     WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAPI_keyxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     WinHttpReq.Send

     myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
     If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile LocalFileName, 2
        oStream.Close
     Else
        MsgBox "Returncode:" & WinHttpReq.Status & " Unable to download picture."
     End If
End function
```